# Estimate number of objects in an environment given agent's observations

Tags: bayesian, estimation, reinforcement-learning, knowledge-discovery

I'm solving a reinforcement learning-like problem, where I have an agent trying to survive in a 2D room. These room contains a finite and constant number of moving objects that interact with an agent. The number of objects is not known to the agent, but she can distinguish one from another when she encounters them.
The task is to model agent's estimation of a number of objects in the room and the way she updates her beliefs.
What are the possible solutions to this or which buzzwords should I Google to find related papers?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider:

- Population size estimation (e.g. [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.2193/2009-305)).
- Counting people (e.g. [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6054049))
- [Mark and recapture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture).
- Knowledge acquisition & reinforcement learning (e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08554))
- Reinforcement learning & estimation (e.g. [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45110-2_2))